# Cloning Skullbriar

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Will a creature that is a copy of [Skullbriar, the Walking Grave](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSkullbriar%2c%20the%20Walking%20Grave%5d) retain it's counters as it moves to another zone? For instance, if a [Clone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bClone%5d) enters the battlefield as a copy of Skullbriar, later gains counters, is sent to the graveyard, and then enters the battlefield from the graveyard as a different creature, will it still have its counters? (Is this answer different if the Clone, upon re-entering the battlefield, becomes a copy of Skullbriar again?)

Similar but different question: if [Lazav, Dimir Mastermind](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLazav%2c%20Dimir%20Mastermind%5d) becomes a copy of Skullbriar, gains counters, and then is sent to the command zone, will it retain the counters? If Lazav is cast as a commander again, will it retain those counters as it enters the battlefield the second time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Clone will lose the counters, since it stops being a Skullbriar as soon as it hits the graveyard. See the rulings below the card in Gatherer:

> If a card becomes a copy of Skullbriar, counters will remain on that card when it leaves the battlefield (unless it goes to your hand or library). Once it does so, it stops being a copy of Skullbriar, so those counters will cease to exist when that card next changes zones.

The same holds for Lazav; it stops being a Skullbriar as soon as it leaves the battlefield.

Comment: D'oh, the very first ruling, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks. Although the wording of 'counters will remain on that card when it leaves the battlefield'  and 'those counters will cease to exist when that card next changes zones' seems to imply the counters remain on the clone while in the graveyard, but don't stay on if that card leaves the graveyard.